# Error with the syntax of the list argument

Tags: python, list

Here is the code I've been working on, a simple Tic Tac Toe game .. I have  researched about this error but i could not seem to find the proper solution 
the code being:

```
def isSpaceFree(board,move):
     return board[move]==' '


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

def getPlayerMove(board):
    move=' '
    while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isSpaceFree(board,move):
        print('Your chance,what square do you want to play in ?')
        move=input()
    return int(move)
while gameIsPlaying:
    if turn == 'player':
        # Player's turn.
    drawBoard(theBoard)
    move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Python33\FirstTime.py", line 162, in <module>
     move=getPlayerMove(theBoard)   
File "C:\Python33\FirstTime.py", line 82, in getPlayerMove
     while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isSpaceFree(board,move):
File "C:\Python33\FirstTime.py", line 75, in isSpaceFree
     return not board[move]== 'X' or board[move]=='O' TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: can you provide the content of borad ,pls

Comment: This traceback from another version of the code, right?

Answer (score 2):

The [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) function returns a string. So you need to cast the `move` variable before trying to use it as an list index.

This function should work:

```
 def isSpaceFree(board,move):
     return board[int(move)]==' '
```

or even better, with your original `isSpaceFree` method:

```
def getPlayerMove(board):
    move = -1  # initialize a 'out of range' number, not an empty string, for consistency
    while move not in range(1, 10) or not isSpaceFree(board,move):
        print('Your chance,what square do you want to play in ?')
        try:
            move = int(input())  # parse number on the fly
        except ValueError:  # if the user doesn't enter a number, display an error
            print('Please enter a number')
            move = -1

    return move
```

For information:

```
>>> range(1, 10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the first value of move which should be integer
so you can make it = something like 10 and cast it when calling the function

```
def getPlayerMove(board):
    move='10'
    while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isSpaceFree(board,int(move)):
        print('Your chance,what square do you want to play in ?')
        move=input()
    return int(move)
```

Answer (score 0):

`move` is a string at first (`' '`). To use it as an index in a list, you need to use an int. You can cast your string to an int using `int(move)`.

You should use

```
move = 0
```

as initialization, and

```
while move not in range(1, 10) ...
```

as a test, since input already returns an int.